Error in NEB calculation
I am getting an error when trying to perform an NEB calculation:
Error in routine card_atomic_positions (2): two occurrences

I tested a simple calculation before and it was working fine. I think there is a problem with the K-points, but I'm not sure how to fix it.
Thank you.
Here`s the input file:
BEGIN
BEGIN_PATH_INPUT
&PATH
  restart_mode      = 'from_scratch'
  string_method     = 'neb',
  nstep_path        = 150,
  ds                = 1.D0,
  opt_scheme        = "broyden",
  num_of_images     = 7,
  CI_scheme         = 'no-CI',
  path_thr          = 0.05D0,
/
END_PATH_INPUT
BEGIN_ENGINE_INPUT
&CONTROL
  prefix         = "Neb1"
  pseudo_dir = "/gpfs/home/s362484/pseudopot"
  outdir= "./"
/
&system
    a                         =  1.06742e+01
    c                         =  4.65880e+01
    degauss                   =  1.00000e-02
    ecutrho                   =  2.25000e+02
    ecutwfc                   =  2.50000e+01
    ibrav                     = 4
    nat                       = 80
    ntyp                      = 5
    occupations               = "smearing"
    smearing                  = "gaussian"
    starting_magnetization(1) =  0.00000e+00
    starting_magnetization(2) =  2.00000e-01
/
&ELECTRONS
    conv_thr         =  1.00000e-05
    electron_maxstep = 1001
    mixing_beta      =  4.00000e-01
/
&IONS
/
ATOMIC_SPECIES
Ru    101.07000  Ru.pbe-spn-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF
Pt    195.07800  Pt.pbe-n-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF
C      12.01070  C.pbe-n-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF
H       1.00794  H.pbe-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF
O      15.99940  O.pbe-nl-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF
/

K_POINTS {gamma}
4 4 4 1 1 1
BEGIN_POSITIONS
FIRST_IMAGE
ATOMIC_POSITIONS {angstrom}
Ru     -0.065919   3.032222   8.318543
Pt      3.903615   0.685619   8.378004
Pt      2.606838   3.041582   8.537927
...
C       3.302951   4.874075  10.714625
C       3.279659   3.411146  10.657303
C       4.587083   2.751321  10.735804
C       5.812081   3.492028  10.716704
C       5.844872   4.958714  10.625467
C       4.534420   5.631534  10.748425
H       6.682851   5.452335  11.151564
H       6.731492   2.996793  11.068011
H       4.607310   1.714157  11.106642
H       2.450546   2.918378  11.198736
H       2.404316   5.387043  11.092918
C       4.428448   6.985682  11.366943
O       5.633944   7.461575  11.823709
O       3.370590   7.608459  11.536089
H       5.431690   8.357865  12.192737
H       1.617138   3.290059   9.670931
LAST_IMAGE
ATOMIC_POSITIONS {angstrom}
Ru     -0.077355   3.037259   8.346787
Pt      3.902203   0.712489   8.439945
Pt      2.610079   3.045290   8.596285
...
C       3.108881   4.576449  11.230801
C       3.192414   3.160385  10.688648
C       4.575933   2.648714  10.704262
C       5.702772   3.530375  10.704618
C       5.561856   4.984420  10.588326
C       4.165588   5.495311  10.599127
H       6.370253   5.526473  11.103695
H       6.648770   3.071659  11.056688
H       4.665625   1.586435  11.030019
H       2.428779   2.509337  11.163505
H       2.119627   5.057803  11.076180
C       3.942680   6.914219  10.960723
O       4.870831   7.478547  11.778207
O       2.895171   7.577683  10.665514
H       4.621185   8.436037  11.855567
H       3.296984   4.530643  12.337758
END_POSITIONS
END_ENGINE_INPUT
END


The K_POINTS line should be just K_POINT {gamma}. Delete the next 4 4 4 1 1 1 line which I suppose you put there because probably you were using K_POINTS {automatic}, previously. Also, ATOMIC_SPECIES is a card, not a namelist. So, there should not be any / at the end of that card.

Hello, I tested what you suggested and the same error happened.
